# 3-D vector projection formula inconsistency

Tags: calculus

Firstly, the formula in the book is this: $F=F_{ab ||} + F_{ab \bot}$

If we have a vector in 3-D space, say $(2, -3, 2)$ and we want to find the parallel component to the x axis, then we can use the dot product to find that the vector parallel to the x axis is $(2, 0, 0$) and according to that formula the vector perpendicular to the x axis has to be $(0,-3,2)$ but according to the dot product, these two vectors aren't perpendicular:  $2*0-9+4=3$

Did I make a mistake somewhere? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But shouldn't $F_{ab \bot}$ be perpendicular to $F$ and not $F_{ab||}$

Comment: No. You project on two perpendicular subspaces but the projected vector has not to be perpendicular to any of them. Think of the projection of $(1,1)$ over the $OX$ and $OY$ axes.